# sorting multidimensional array numerically and lexicographically javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have been breaking my brain for the last 2 days trying to find a solution to the problem but I can't figure it out.

I need to sort an array of arrays first numerically and then lexicographically. While a custom a < b function can solve the first, a normal array.sort() can do the second. But I have no clue how to combine them.

I have an array similar to this one:

```js
var arr = [
    [ '80', '1', '230' ],
    [ '9', '1', '230' ],
    [ 'Ken', '6', '100' ],
    [ 'Dan', '2', '800' ],
    [ 'Tom', '6', '500' ],
    [ 'team10', '2', '222' ],
    [ 'team9', '2', '222' ]
  ];
```

This array needs to be sorted numerically first according to the numbers in arr[n][1] (largest to smallest). Results with the same arr[n][1] value need to them be ordered numerically according to arr[n][2] (largest to smallest). And finally results with the same value [n][1] and [n][2] need to be ordered lexigographically based on arr[n][0].

The farthest I have gotten so far is this approach:

```js
function sortArr() {
       arr.sort(function(a,b) {
          if (a[1] === b[1]) {
              if (a[2] === b[2]) {
                  return b[0] < a[0];
              }
              return a[2]-b[2];
          }
          return b[1]-a[1]
      });
  }
```

While the numerical sorting works with this, the lexicographical sorting doesn't. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a chained approach with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) for strings.

Sort order:

- at index 1 desc
- at index 2 desc
- at index 0

  - not nummerical part asc
  - nummerical part asc

```js
var arr = [[ '80', '1', '230' ], [ '9', '1', '230' ], [ 'Ken', '6', '100' ], [ 'Dan', '2', '800' ], [ 'Tom', '6', '500' ], [ 'team10', '2', '222' ], [ 'team9', '2', '222' ]];

arr.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aa = a[0].split(/(\d+)/g),
        bb = b[0].split(/(\d+)/g);

    return b[1] - a[1] ||
        b[2] - a[2] ||
        aa[0].localeCompare(bb[0]) || aa[1] - bb[1];
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thank you Nina. Same issue. If you swap team10 and team9 in the original array and run your code, they will not be sorted correctly.

Comment: This is because `1 < 9` you have to parse the numbers and compare them then instead of per character compare